# Zero-knowledge card shuffle

Tags: cryptography, protocols

I'm trying to design a zero-knowledge protocol for the creation of a shuffled deck of cards for use by two players. Naturally this requires that neither player knows the order of the cards after the shuffle, nor what card was drawn by the other during play, but I'd also *like* to be able to do this without needing a trusted third party as well.

My best efforts so far require (only) a trusted third party for game set up (which is better than requiring a "dealer" for every draw) but I'd love to be able to remove even that, if possible!

My protocol so far — game set up:

1. Both players generate N=52 asymmetric encryption keys and sends to the trusted third party (3P).
2. 3P picks a salt for use everywhere.
3. 3P encrypts "A♣️ ", "2♣️ ", "3♣️ ", … N, each with a different (randomly chosen) public key from player 1.
4. 3P encrypts the results of step (3) with a different (randomly chosen) public key from player 2.
5. 3P now makes these "shuffled card" encrypted values public so both players can see and use.

Protocol for player 1 "drawing a card":

1. Player 2 shares the private key from the the top "shuffled card" on the stack, and records it as "dealt to player 1".
2. Player 1 iterates through each combination of player 2's private key player 2 provided + each of the private keys they have, and tries decrypting the top "shuffled card" with the combo until success. (I'm unconcerned with the up to N² decryptions here)
3. Player 1 records the secret key of theirs that worked as "dealt to player 1", removes the salt, and uses the indicated card in the game.
4. (When player 1 plays that card they can prove it was one they had by sharing the secret key that decrypted it back to player 2, so they can validate)

Can anyone offer a suggestion as to how I could approach removing the need of a trusted third party for the initialisation, so neither player is advantaged?

Comment: This is probably better addressed to crypto.stackexchange.com. It's an interesting problem, but not a programming problem.

Comment: Oh! My mistake — I thought this came under the "algorithm" part of "with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems." — I'll post there instead 

Comment: I'm closing this because it was recommended to move to Crypto Stack Exchange. See here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/107226/zero-knowledge-card-shuffle

Comment: Cool. If they fuss at you that you shouldn't have moved it over there, blame me and we'll reopen :D (But I'm pretty certain I'm right, and there are some really sharp cryptography folks over there that I think can help.)

Comment: Superb — thanks Rob! I appreciate the help!